# Get heading and pitch from pixels on Street View

Tags: javascript, math, google-maps-api-3, geometry, google-street-view

I think this is the best place for this question.

I am trying to get the heading and pitch of any clicked point on an embedded Google Street View.

The only pieces of information I know and can get are:

- The field of view (degrees)
- The center point's heading and pitch (in degrees) and x and y pixel position
- The x and y pixel position of the mouse click

I've included here a screenshot with simplified measurements as an example:

[image: Screenshot with measurements]

I initally just thought you could divide the field of view by the pixel width to get degrees per pixel, but it's more complicated, I think it has to do with projecting onto the inside of a sphere, where the camera is at the centre of the sphere?

Bonus if you can tell me how to do the reverse too...

**Clarification:**
The goal is not to move the view to the clicked point, but give information about a clicked point. The degrees per pixel method doesn't work because the viewport is not linear.

THe values I have here are just examples, but the field of view can be bigger or smaller (from [0.something, 180], and the center is not fixed, it could be any value in the range [0, 360] and vertically [-90, 90]. The point [0, 0] is simply the heading (horizontal degrees) and pitch (vertical degrees) of the photogapher when the photo was taken, and doesn't really represent anything.

Comment: is this question better for StackOverflow perhaps? If so, could someone move it for me?

Comment: what is against the degrees per pixel idea?  even if it gives some error, doing it constantly will get you to the point you want to get to, but also the question is not very clear , is $ 0^o , 0^o  $ horizontal ahead? (should it then not be close to the horizon, or is the road going downhill,  or is it for a plane?) and is $ 90^o , 0^o $ looking right? It is all a bit unclear can you add much more detail

Comment: @Willemien thanks, I've added clarification to the question.

Comment: Can the view ever reach **exactly** 180°? I'm considering a solution that takes the clicked point, plots it on a chord, draws a line from the origin to the point, then continues the line onto an arc. This solution could work, but it would break down if `lengthOfChord == diameter` (i.e. a 180° angle).

Comment: Yes it could reach exactly 180, but if you need to approximate it, you could set it to 180.00001 in this specific case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: JavaScript code for a proof of concept included at the end of this answer.

The heading and pitch parameters `h0` and `p0` of the panorama image corresponds to a direction. By using the focal length `f` of the camera to scale this direction vector, one can get the 3D coordinates `(x0, y0, z0)` of the viewport center at `(u0, v0)`:

```
x0 = f * cos( p0 ) * sin( h0 )
y0 = f * cos( p0 ) * cos( h0 )
z0 = f * sin( p0 )
```

The goal is now to find the 3D coordinates of the point at to some given pixel coordinates `(u, v)` in the image. First, map these pixel coordinates to pixel offsets `(du, dv)` (to the right and to the top) from the viewport center:

```
du = u - u0 = u - w / 2
dv = v0 - v = h / 2 - v
```

Then a local orthonormal 2D basis of the viewport in 3D has to be found. The unit vector `(ux, uy, uz)` supports the x-axis (to the right along the direction of increasing headings) and the vector `(vx, vy, vz)` supports the y-axis (to the top along the direction of increasing pitches) of the image. Once these two vectors are determined, the 3D coordinates of the point on the viewport matching the `(du, dv)` pixel offset in the viewport are simply:

```
x = x0 + du * ux + dv * vx
y = y0 + du * uy + dv * vy
z = z0 + du * uz + dv * vz
```

And the heading and pitch parameters `h` and `p` for this point are then:

```
R = sqrt( x * x + y * y + z * z )
h = atan2( x, y )
p = asin( z / R )
```

Finally to get the two unit vectors `(ux, uy, uz)` and `(vx, vy, vz)`, compute the derivatives of the spherical coordinates by the heading and pitch parameters at `(p0, h0)`, and one should get:

```
vx = -sin( p0 ) * sin ( h0 )
vy = -sin( p0 ) * cos ( h0 )
vz =  cos( p0 ) 

ux =  sgn( cos ( p0 ) ) * cos( h0 )
uy = -sgn( cos ( p0 ) ) * sin( h0 )
uz = 0
```

where `sgn( a )` is `+1` if `a >= 0` else `-1`.

Complements:

- The focal length is derived from the horizontal field of view and the width of the image:

  ```
  f = (w / 2) / Math.tan(fov / 2)
  ```
- The reverse mapping from heading and pitch parameters to pixel coordinates can be done similarly:

  1. Find the 3D coordinates `(x, y, z)` of the direction of the ray corresponding to the specified heading and pitch parameters,
  2. Find the 3D coordinates `(x0, y0, z0)` of the direction of the ray corresponding to the viewport center (an associated image plane is located at `(x0, y0, z0)` with an `(x0, y0, z0)` normal),
  3. Intersect the ray for the specified heading and pitch parameters with the image plane, this gives the 3D offset from the viewport center,
  4. Project this 3D offset on the local basis, getting the 2D offsets `du` and `dv`
  5. Map `du` and `dv` to absolute pixel coordinates.
- In practice, this approach seems to work similarly well on both square and rectangular viewports.

Proof of concept code (call the `onLoad()` function on a web page containing a sized canvas element with a "panorama" id)

```
'use strict';

var viewer;

function onClick(e) {
  viewer.click(e);
}

function onLoad() {
  var element = document.getElementById("panorama");
  viewer = new PanoramaViewer(element);
  viewer.update();
}

function PanoramaViewer(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.width = element.width;
  this.height = element.height;
  this.pitch = 0;
  this.heading = 0;

  element.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);
}

PanoramaViewer.FOV = 90;

PanoramaViewer.prototype.makeUrl = function() {
  var fov = PanoramaViewer.FOV;

  return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=40.457375,-80.009353&size=" + this.width + "x" + this.height + "&fov=" + fov + "&heading=" + this.heading + "&pitch=" + this.pitch;
}

PanoramaViewer.prototype.update = function() {
  var element = this.element;

  element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.makeUrl() + ")";

  var width = this.width;
  var height = this.height;

  var context = element.getContext('2d');

  context.strokeStyle = '#FFFF00';

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, height / 2);
  context.lineTo(width, height / 2);
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(width / 2, 0);
  context.lineTo(width / 2, height);
  context.stroke();
}

function sgn(x) {
  return x >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
}

PanoramaViewer.prototype.unmap = function(heading, pitch) {
  var PI = Math.PI
  var cos = Math.cos;
  var sin = Math.sin;
  var tan = Math.tan;

  var fov = PanoramaViewer.FOV * PI / 180.0;
  var width = this.width;
  var height = this.height;

  var f = 0.5 * width / tan(0.5 * fov);

  var h = heading * PI / 180.0;
  var p = pitch * PI / 180.0;

  var x = f * cos(p) * sin(h);
  var y = f * cos(p) * cos(h);
  var z = f * sin(p);

  var h0 = this.heading * PI / 180.0;
  var p0 = this.pitch * PI / 180.0;

  var x0 = f * cos(p0) * sin(h0);
  var y0 = f * cos(p0) * cos(h0);
  var z0 = f * sin(p0);

  //
  // Intersect the ray O, v = (x, y, z)
  // with the plane at M0 of normal n = (x0, y0, z0)
  //
  //   n . (O + t v - M0) = 0
  //   t n . v = n . M0 = f^2
  //
  var t = f * f / (x0 * x + y0 * y + z0 * z);

  var ux = sgn(cos(p0)) * cos(h0);
  var uy = -sgn(cos(p0)) * sin(h0);
  var uz = 0;

  var vx = -sin(p0) * sin(h0);
  var vy = -sin(p0) * cos(h0);
  var vz = cos(p0);

  var x1 = t * x;
  var y1 = t * y;
  var z1 = t * z;

  var dx10 = x1 - x0;
  var dy10 = y1 - y0;
  var dz10 = z1 - z0;

  // Project on the local basis (u, v) at M0
  var du = ux * dx10 + uy * dy10 + uz * dz10;
  var dv = vx * dx10 + vy * dy10 + vz * dz10;

  return {
    u: du + width / 2,
    v: height / 2 - dv,
  };
}

PanoramaViewer.prototype.map = function(u, v) {
  var PI = Math.PI;
  var cos = Math.cos;
  var sin = Math.sin;
  var tan = Math.tan;
  var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
  var atan2 = Math.atan2;
  var asin = Math.asin;

  var fov = PanoramaViewer.FOV * PI / 180.0;
  var width = this.width;
  var height = this.height;

  var h0 = this.heading * PI / 180.0;
  var p0 = this.pitch * PI / 180.0;

  var f = 0.5 * width / tan(0.5 * fov);

  var x0 = f * cos(p0) * sin(h0);
  var y0 = f * cos(p0) * cos(h0);
  var z0 = f * sin(p0);

  var du = u - width / 2;
  var dv = height / 2 - v;

  var ux = sgn(cos(p0)) * cos(h0);
  var uy = -sgn(cos(p0)) * sin(h0);
  var uz = 0;

  var vx = -sin(p0) * sin(h0);
  var vy = -sin(p0) * cos(h0);
  var vz = cos(p0);

  var x = x0 + du * ux + dv * vx;
  var y = y0 + du * uy + dv * vy;
  var z = z0 + du * uz + dv * vz;

  var R = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
  var h = atan2(x, y);
  var p = asin(z / R);

  return {
    heading: h * 180.0 / PI,
    pitch: p * 180.0 / PI
  };
}

PanoramaViewer.prototype.click = function(e) {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var u = e.clientX - rect.left;
  var v = e.clientY - rect.top;

  var uvCoords = this.unmap(this.heading, this.pitch);

  console.log("current viewport center");
  console.log("  heading: " + this.heading);
  console.log("  pitch: " + this.pitch);
  console.log("  u: " + uvCoords.u)
  console.log("  v: " + uvCoords.v);

  var hpCoords = this.map(u, v);
  uvCoords = this.unmap(hpCoords.heading, hpCoords.pitch);

  console.log("click at (" + u + "," + v + ")");
  console.log("  heading: " + hpCoords.heading);
  console.log("  pitch: " + hpCoords.pitch);
  console.log("  u: " + uvCoords.u);
  console.log("  v: " + uvCoords.v);

  this.heading = hpCoords.heading;
  this.pitch = hpCoords.pitch;
  this.update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant - is there no way at all to get this working for rectangular viewports?

Comment: @TimRodham I guess it should be possible to adapt this to non-square viewports. Unfortunately, I have a transatlantic flight to catch, so this won't happen soon...

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, I'm giving you the bounty as this is the closest to what I needed

Comment: sorry to bring this one back up, but I don't suppose you could add to your fiddle the reverse method? I'm having trouble implementing your step 3...

Comment: @TimRodham Updated with the reverse mapping. I still need to figure it out for non-square viewports :-)

Comment: @TimRodham Did anyone try this with rectangular viewports?

Comment: @Geekster I added some PoC JS code since the jsfiddle link expired. Unless I am mistaken, the approach should work with rectangular viewports as long as the FoV derivation is correct... In practice, after playing a bit with it on square and rectangular viewports, I am getting similar results, so I modified the comment accordingly...

Comment: This is awesome! I will report back with my results. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3146587 Thanks for an amazing answer. It possible to calculate the actual height from ground of a given pixel?

Comment: @user3146587 I actually put this in a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219613/height-of-a-pixel-from-ground-in-google-street-view

Answer (score 4):

**This answer is unprecise, have a look at most recent answer of user3146587.**

I'm not very good at mathematical explanations. I've coded an example and tried to explain the steps in the code. As soon as you click on one point in the image, this point becomes the new center of the image. Even though you have explicitly not demanded for this, this is perfect for illustrating the effect. The new image is drawn with the previously calculated angle.

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnh84/2/)

The important part is, that I use the [radian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) to calculate radius of the "sphere of view". The radian in this case is the width of the image (in your example 100)

```
radius = radian / FOV
```

With the radian, radius and the relative position of the mouse position I can calculate the degree that changes from the center to the mouse position.

```
Center(50,50)
MousePosition(75/25)
RelativeMousePosition(25,-25)
```

When the relative mouse position is 25 the radian used for the calculation of the horizontal angle is 50.

```
radius = 50 / FOV // we've calculated the radius before, it stays the same
```

See this image for the further process:
[image]

I can calculate the new heading and pitch when I add/subtract the calculated angle to the actual angle (depending on left/right, above/under). See the linked JSFiddle for the correct behavior of this.

Doing the reverse is simple, just do the listed steps in the opposite direction (the radius stays the same).

As I've already mentioned, I'm not very good at mathematical explanations, but don't hesitate to ask questions in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, unfortunately the fiddle you've given isn't quite accurate - if you click on the corner of a building for example, you'd expect the image to be centred on that corner, but it is offset slightly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to give a mathematical derivation of the answer to your question.

Note: Unfortunately, this derivation only works in 1D and the conversion from a pair of angular deviations to heading and pitch is wrong.

Notations:

`f`: focal length of the camera
`h`: height in pixels of the viewport
`w`: width in pixels of the viewport
`dy`: vertical deviation in pixels from the center of the viewport
`dx`: horizontal deviation in pixels from the center of the viewport
`fov_y`: vertical field of view
`fov_x`: horizontal field of view
`dtheta_y`: relative vertical angle from the center of the viewport
`dtheta_x`: relative horizontal angle from the center of the viewport

Given `dy`, the vertical offset of the pixel from the center of the viewport (this pixel corresponds to the green ray on the figure), we are trying to find `dtheta_y` (the red angle), the relative vertical angle from the center of the viewport (the pitch of the center of the viewport is known to be `theta_y0`).

[image: Notations]

From the figure, we have:

```
tan( fov_y / 2 ) = ( h / 2 ) / f

tan( dtheta_y ) = dy / f
```

so:

```
tan( dtheta_y ) = dy / ( ( h / 2 ) / tan( fov_y / 2 ) )
                = 2 * dy * tan( fov_y /  2 ) / h
```

and finally:

```
dtheta_y = atan( 2 * dy * tan( fov_y / 2 ) / h )
```

This is the relative pitch angle for the pixel at `dy` from the center of the viewport, simply add to it the pitch angle at the center of the viewport to get the absolute pitch angle (i.e. `theta_y = theta_y0 + dtheta_y`).

similarly:

```
dtheta_x = atan( 2 * dx * tan( fov_x / 2 ) / w )
```

This is the relative heading angle for the pixel at `dx` from the center of the viewport.

Complements:

- Both relations can be inverted to get the mapping from relative heading / pitch angle to relative pixel coordinates, for instance:

  ```
  dy = h tan( dtheta_y ) / ( 2 * tan( fov_y / 2 ) )
  ```
- The vertical and horizontal fields of view `fov_y` and `fov_x` are linked by the relation:

  ```
  w / h = tan( fov_x / 2 ) / tan( fov_y / 2 )
  ```

  so:

  ```
  fov_x = 2 * atan( w * tan( fov_y / 2 ) / h )
  ```
- The vertical and horizontal deviations from the viewport center `dy` and `dx` can be mapped to absolute pixel coordinates:

  ```
  x = w / 2 + dx
  y = h / 2 - dy
  ```
- Proof of concept [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Yc5/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, this looks solid, but unfortunately in practice it is not accurate. I wonder if Street View is not using a sphere... Would you mind coding a fiddle to ensure I have translated this properly into code and not made a silly mistake?

Comment: @TimRodham I've just added a proof of concept.

Comment: That's great thanks, unfortunately it's the same problem as the other answer, there seems to be accuracy issues. Look here - I've added a red div to the centre of the image. If you click on landmarks you can see sometimes they are offset from the centre - http://jsfiddle.net/T9Yc5/2/

Comment: @TimRodham Indeed, see my other answer, this one appears to work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Matysiak wrote a JS library that implements the inverse of this (placing a marker at a specific heading/pitch). I mention this as the various jsfiddle links in other answers are 404ing, the original requestor added a comment requesting this, and this SO page comes up near the top for related searches.

The blog post discussing it is at https://martinmatysiak.de/blog/view/panomarker.

The library itself is at https://github.com/marmat/google-maps-api-addons.

There's documentation and demos at http://marmat.github.io/google-maps-api-addons/ (look at http://marmat.github.io/google-maps-api-addons/panomarker/examples/basic.html and http://marmat.github.io/google-maps-api-addons/panomarker/examples/fancy.html for the PanoMarker examples).